# How to resolve E303 (Unable to open swap file) on Linux machine?

Tags: linux, swap-file

I get E303 (*Unable to open swap file for "{filename}", recovery impossible*) when I open a file in vim in my Ubuntu system.

I see that the backupdir and directory environment variables are set correctly in vim -

`:se backupdir`

> backupdir=~/tools/Vim_Files/vim_backup

`:se directory`

> directory=~/tools/Vim_Files/vim_backup

This is the output of ls -l in the shell -
`ls -l ~/tools/Vim_Files/`

> drwxrwxr-x  2 me  me  4096 Oct 12 17:02 vim_backup

This is the relevant portion of my .vimrc setting up these variables -

```
se nobackup writebackup
let s:vim_cstmztn_files_dir='~/tools/Vim_Files/'   
let &directory=s:vim_cstmztn_files_dir.'vim_backup'
let &backupdir=s:vim_cstmztn_files_dir.'vim_backup'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vim does not interpolate the `~` when using the `let &` syntax.  You must do this manually using `expand()`.

```
se nobackup writebackup
let s:vim_cstmztn_files_dir=expand('~/tools/Vim_Files/')
let &directory=s:vim_cstmztn_files_dir.'vim_backup'
let &backupdir=s:vim_cstmztn_files_dir.'vim_backup'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when there was a space after the path of the swap file directory.

```
backupdir=~/tools/Vim_Files/vim_backup"     "
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I [edit]ed your post to use code-formatting. I assumed the quotes were just there to indicate the spaces? If so, you might want to [edit] and indicate that. Also, "I have this problem too" is generally a poor answer—a better answer would state "This is how I fixed it when I had this problem." You can also [edit] to add such details.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure that your disk in not full. This error can also occur when there are no more free disk space to create swap file.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!